# Enabling Chrome Custom Tabs for Facebook login using Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0, chrome-custom-tabs

I am using Facebook SDK version 4.11.0 in my app.

As per the steps outlined on the [Official docs page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android), I have added following things inside manifest file to enable Chrome Custom Tabs.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

`fb_login_protocol_scheme` is added to `strings.xml` with value **'fb+app_id'**

Authentication process is working fine without any issue.
Only concern is when I click on login button, the login dialog doesn't opens up in Chrome Custom Tabs but in the usual webview dialog format.

Is there something here missing to be added to the project to enable Chrome Custom Tabs?

Comment: Are you sure that the Chrome version installed on your device supports the Chrome Custom Tabs?

Comment: Yes! I have another app on phone downloaded from playstore which uses facebook sdk 4.11 as well and when i click on facebook login button in that app it opens in custom chrome tabs..but not in my case

Comment: no doc has where to get fb_login_protocol_sheme. ('fb_login_protocol_scheme is added to strings.xml with value 'fb+app_id'')found here. why don't they put that in doc?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check why Chrome Custom Tabs doesn't work with this snippet:

```
private static final String CUSTOM_TABS_SERVICE_ACTION = "android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService";
private static final String CHROME_PACKAGE = "com.android.chrome";

private boolean isCustomTabsAllowed(Context context) {
    boolean isCustomTabsAllowed = true;

    if (!isCustomTabsEnabled(context)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "isCustomTabsEnabled false");
        isCustomTabsAllowed = false;
    }

    if (!isChromeCustomTabsSupported(context)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "isChromeCustomTabsSupported false");
        isCustomTabsAllowed = false;
    }

    if (!Validate.hasCustomTabRedirectActivity(context)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "hasCustomTabRedirectActivity false");
        isCustomTabsAllowed = false;
    }

    return isCustomTabsAllowed;
}

private boolean isCustomTabsEnabled(Context context) {
    final String appId = Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(context);
    final Utility.FetchedAppSettings settings = Utility.getAppSettingsWithoutQuery(appId);
    return settings != null && settings.getCustomTabsEnabled();
}

private boolean isChromeCustomTabsSupported(final Context context) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(CUSTOM_TABS_SERVICE_ACTION);
    serviceIntent.setPackage(CHROME_PACKAGE);
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos =
            context.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0);
    return !(resolveInfos == null || resolveInfos.isEmpty());
}
```

These are the methods called by the Facebook SDK before launch the Chrome Custom Tabs, so simply calling `isCustomTabsAllowed` you can understand what's wrong with your app.

If `isCustomTabsEnabled` is false there is some problem in the configuration of your app. Verify on Facebook console under *App Review* section that the app is live and available to the public.

If `isChromeCustomTabsSupported` is false probably you have an older version of Chrome that doesn't support the Chrome Custom Tabs, try to update to the last version of Chrome.

If `hasCustomTabRedirectActivity` is false there are some issues in the integration, verify that you correctly followed all the steps indicated in the [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android#chrome_custom_tabs). Also verify that the APP_ID is the same used in the string `facebook_app_id` otherwise the login dialog won't use the Chrome Custom Tabs.

Comment: Yes, I have verified the value of string `fb_login_protocol_scheme` is correct with value `fbAPP_ID`..All authentication process is working fine too..Are Chrome Custom Tabs not working because I have been using my development key hash in the project settings i.e. the app hasn't been deployed to playstore?                                                              **Note:** Also, when the facebook android app is installed on phone it properly redirects to facebook login page inside facebook's android app.. Thanks for your valuable time! :)

Comment: I have just updated the answer. Let me know the result of your test!

Comment: `isCustomTabsAllowed` is returning false(due to `isCustomTabsEnabled` method returning false.)                                                                                 Need to dig a little bit deeper as to why is `isCustomTabsEnabled` returning false? Thanks for your help..really appreciate it! Meanwhile if you are able to find out the reason for that method returning false do let me know..Thanks again!

Comment: Seems that your app doesn't allow the login through the Chrome Custom Tabs. Verify in your Facebook Developer console if the option
`Embedded Browser OAuth Login` under `Facebook Login > Client OAuth Settings` is enabled

Comment: I have option `Embedded Browser OAuth Login` enabled in App's Client OAuth settings..What I observed when looking at `Utility` class of Facebook sdk is that settings like `enable chrome custom tabs` and other such settings are received by graph api call as soon as `Facebooksdk.initialize(getApplicationContext())` is called. Once we receive response then those values are stored in sharedprefs by facebook sdk..In my case(App) I observed that call made to graph service api which is used to fetch those settings is getting Http 400 as response

Comment: As a result it is taking default boolean value of `false` for variable related to customtabs setting and causing this issue

Comment: Graph API call made by every app: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<AppID>?fields=supports_implicit_sdk_logging%2Cgdpv4_nux_content%2Cgdpv4_nux_enabled%2Cgdpv4_chrome_custom_tabs_enabled%2Candroid_dialog_configs%2Candroid_sdk_error_categories%2Capp_events_session_timeout&format=json&sdk=android`

Comment: Ideal response should be received one of such value as :`"gdpv4_chrome_custom_tabs_enabled": true` but in my app I am receiving Http 400 response with following error :  [error response](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/droidwala/877d345258730fcb7a20885a7b174e0e/raw/9c0989f545ca1daeb4605f6dc8df7ddb1d983cfc/response.json)

Comment: Is your application live and available to the public? You can verify it under `App Review` section

Comment: Cool!! Yup you got it right, my application was not available public as result those graph api call were returning Http 400 response causing this issue. Thanks a lot for your help! Have a nice day! :)

Comment: Wait so if you app is not yet on the Google Play Store, then the chrome custom tabs will not work?

Comment: @toobsco42 No, it is necessary that the app is live on **Facebook** console. It's not important the status on the Google Play Store.

Comment: @MattiaMaestrini how can you tell if an app is live on Facebook console?

Comment: You can verify it under `App Review` section of the Facebook console

Comment: Worked like a charm.  hasCustomTabRedirectActivity returned false.  I missed the detail to prefix my facebook ID with "fb" in fb_login_protocol_scheme.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I've also just had the same situation and the workaround for this is pretty simple I think. If you try to run the application on a real phone, the WebView will automatically switch to CustomTab.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).